Film like Odd Thomas with the man who can see demon is demon himself
Need help figuring out a name of a movie.  It's almost like the movie "Odd Thomas", but in this movie, the man who sees the demons apparently used to be one of them/ He was much stronger. Then they decided to kill him everyday so he wouldn't remember who or what he was. All he knew was that he could see them and when they saw him he'd be killed. These demons were shade-looking things. In one of the scenes, he was inside of a subway and saw this thing hovering around a man. I believe this man was either killed or taken over. Please help me figure out the name.

Need help figuring out this ... "sentence".

Just submitted an edit to clear things up.

@user32869 The Deaths of Ian Stone?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9JjyRc652I

Could be The Deaths of Ian Stone

The story centers on a man, Ian Stone, who is killed each day by mysterious beings. He then enters a new existence, unaware of his prior lives. When he begins to remember past existences, he is once again in danger of being killed, with each death more gruesome than the last.

-

...reveals a shocking truth: Ian was one of these monsters until he rebelled against the colony and managed to kill one other Harvester




